# Docker for windows doesn't work. What could I do with it?

Tags: docker

Yeah, I know, there are some questions similar to that, but none of them helped me. My docker for windows has once stopped working. Now I can't even uninstall it, because in the applications it doesn't appear, I cannot install it, the installation stucks always on the same process, I tried to delete all the files and then install again, tried to stop all the proccesses related to docker, I tried everything. I cannot even uninstall, cannot reinstall, cannot run... cannot do anything with it... help!

Comment: This is hard to hear but I think the only way your going to get out of this problem is a machine wipe. It's because docker cmd line is so integrated when you install it, that when it messes up like this the only solution is a wipe and reload. I had something similar and had to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved that. I deleted manually all the directories related to docker (ProgramFiles, ProgramData, [user root directory], Appdata/Roaming etc.) and this way the installer finally finished. There was another problem, that WSL2 engine tried to start, but couldn't. WSL was enabled, the engine starting process was running for ca. 1 hour... but nothing happend and couldn't even change the engine. So I reinstalled once again, and didn't install the WSL frame. It started automatically with Hyper-V and now it works fine.